# How to speed up frequent writing

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

we created an java agent which does a check on our application suite to see if for instance the parent/child structure is still correct. Therefore it needs to check for 8000+ documents accros several applications.

The check itself goes very fast. We use a navigator to retrieve data from views and only read data from those entries. The problem is within our logging mechanism. Whenever we report a log entry with level SEVERE ( aka: A realy big issue ) the backend document is directly updated. This is becuase we dont want to lose any info about these issues.

In our test runs we see that everything runs smoot but as soon as we 'create' a lot of severe issues the performance drops enormously because of all the writes. I would like to see if there are any notes developers facing the same challenge.. How couuld we speed up the writing without losing any data?

-- added more info after comment from simon --

Its a scheduled agent which runs every night to check for inconsistencies. Goal is ofcourse to find inconsistencies and fix the cause and to eventualy have no inconsistencies reported at all.

Comment: What logging framework is in use? Log4j? Java logging? Some custom stuff?

Comment: Do you have to log to Notes documents? You could use java Logger to write to a text file.

Comment: Custom made logging which uses the java logging framework. Persisting the log is done using notes documents

Comment: How frequently does the agent run? Or how many concurrent agents occur? Is it running via Agent Manager, program document, etc? Are there any embedded jars in the agent? What details do you have on how the write occurs?

Comment: If you are writing each log entry as a file this could be very expensive.  Can you not write a single report which has all the issues in it?

Comment: I was thinking about using a buffered write approach. When there are lets say 10 / 100 issues reported it gets written to document.

Comment: If I undestood correctly the problem is that the server time limit for scheduled agents is set to 15 minutes. Any change that could be extended a bit? It should be no problem if an agent runs f.e. 20 minutes once per night.

Comment: How many writes are being done in the log for each SEVERE entry?  I've seen bad logging implementations that create one document per LINE of data.  I've also seen bad implementations that create just one document for an entire run and keep appending one line of rich text at a time to that one document, and then call document.save() after each line.

Comment: Another thought: 3000 inconsistencies out of 8000 documents seems like an awful lot. Perhaps the better strategy would be to use a counter, and after you get to, say, 100 SEVERE entries, you should recognize that something is very, very, very wrong, write one FATAL entry, change the ACL to lock out non-admins, send a page to the on-call admin and ring as many other alarms as you can think of?

Comment: Richard, that is exactly what this application is going to do. We where only stress testing it and saw a awful increase in time it needed to full fill its task as the number of logged severe issues rose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its a scheduled agent which runs every night to check for
>   inconsistencies.

OK. So there are a number of factors to take into account.

1. Are there any embedded Jars? When an agent has embedded jars the server has to detach them from the agent to the disk before they can run the code. This is done every time the agent executes. This can be a performance hit. If your agent spawns a number of times, remove the embedded jars and put them into the lib\ext folder on the server instead (requires server restart).
2. You mention it runs at night. By default general housekeeping processes run at night. Check the notes ini for Server Tasks scheduled and appraise what impact they have on the server/agent when running. For example:

   ```
   ServerTasksAt1=Catalog,Design
   ServerTasksAt2=Updall
   ServerTasksAt5=Statlog
   ```

   In this case if ran between 2-5 then UPDALL could have an impact on it. Also check program documents for scheduled executions.
3. In what way are you writing? If you are creating a document for each incident and the document contents is not much then the write time should be reasonable. What is liable to be a hit in performance is one of the following.

   - If you are multi threading those writes.
   - Pulling a log document, appending a line, saving and then repeating.

One last thing to think about. If you are getting 3000 errors, there must be a point where X amount of errors means that there is no point continuing and instead to alert the admin via SNMP/email/etc? It might be worth coding that in as well.

Other then that, you should probably post some sample code in relation to the write.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, difficult or general question. 
As far as I understand, you update the documents in the view you are walking through. I would set `view.AutoUpdate` to false. This ensures that the view is not reloaded while you are running your code. This should speed up your code.

This is an extract from the Designer help:

> Avoid automatically updating the parent view by explicitly setting
>   AutoUpdate to False. Automatic updates degrade performance and may
>   invalidate entries in the navigator ("Entry not found in index"). You
>   can update the view as needed with Refresh.

Hope that helps.
If that does not help you might want to post a code fragment or more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate documents for each error rather than one huge document.

or

1. Write to a text file directly rather than a database and then pulling if necessary into a document.  This should speed things up considerably.